# Define if a contour is closed or not

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, recursion, shapes

I need a way to define if a contour represents a line or a closed shape. In Java, I have an object *Shape* which contains all the points which defines it again as separate objects. The object *Point* represents the coordinates of the point. I tried parsing the shapes with a recursion but for larger shapes, more then 150 points, the performance is very poor. I am attaching a picture of the shapes I want to parse to help better understand the question.

I am putting a image for better visualisation of the problem.

[image]

This is just showing all the shapes I got. I want to display just the two closed ones.

Thanks in advance.
Vassil Kossev

Comment: I think you want to tag the question with 'algorithm'?

Comment: Thanks. I knew I forgot something.

Comment: Are the points wound into a ring or just listed in an arbitrary order?

Comment: Do you have to separate closed contours from open ones too? Or you have an algorithm to separate them, and just want to determine whether a given contour is closed or open?

Comment: I want to determine if a given contour from the picture is closed or open. If it is closed I display it if it is open I don't care about it.

Comment: All "contours" are closed, at least with the usage of "contour" with which I'm familiar: the curve of constant value from a continuous function. For example, this image looks like a GIS elevation raster that's been through a really bad contour-tracing algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have contour lines of 1 pixel width, then you **can count the number of neighbors for each point ***. If every point of a given contour has 2 neighbors, then the contour is *closed*. If there are 2 points with only 1 neighbor each, then the contour is *open*.

If your contours are thicker, then you can apply a **skeletonization** algorithm to make them exactly 1 pixel thin. An interesting case is when you have **side branches** on a contour, but in this case there must be branching points with 3 neighbors, so similar situations can be handled easily.

*** Counting neighbors** is easy: use the original image! Choose one point of the contour randomly, check the neighboring 8 pixels, and count those which are part of the contour. Then repeat the neighbor-checking for these, and so on, until all pixels of the contour have been checked.

Comment: Unfortunately, depending on how you count neighbors, you can have multiple points with only one neighbor and still have a closed contour, so the first method you suggest may produce false negatives.

Comment: Precisely that's why I wrote about skeletonization and handling side branches. Years ago I applied this approach in a program which extracted the coordinates of points of scanned graphs (figures of scientific articles). I had curved, noisy thick lines, so I had to smooth them first a bit. Then I applied my skeletonization algorithm, and after that, I removed the side branches. I processed similarly not just the graph lines, but the axes of the graph, too, so as a last step, the program could calibrate the points of the graph lines, and save them for using directly in Matlab and Excel :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this idea. I decided to use this one because it is the simpliest and most straight-forward and this is what I needed.

Answer (score 8):

First idea: Use a suitable [contour tracing algorithm](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html) to get an ordered contour. If your contour is closed you will get back to the first point eventually.

Second idea: Use a [flood filling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill): if you get out of the bounding box of your object it is open, otherwise it is closed.

Third idea: use morphology. Remove lone pixels. Find all endpoints and branchpoints. Remove all branchpoints. Connected components with no endpoints are closed contours ("circles"), connected components with two endpoints are open contours ("lines"). Re-project connected components with no endpoints to the original image and keep only connected components that have common part with them. I think this could be implemented real-time, and the easiest to implement.

Comment: Fourth idea (deleted because I'm not sure if it's working): choose a point that is surely inside your object (eg. point of mass for convex objects) and draw radial lines with angle of reasonably small steps. If the number of intersections of your object's contour and the lines is always odd - you have a closed contour. Otherwise your object is open.

Answer (score 1):

If the points are stored in order, you might be able to compare the first and last points. If they're spatially equal, the contour is closed.

Comment: Unfortunately the points are not sorted. But if there is a way to sort them it will be useful. What can be the criteria for sorting the coordinates?

Comment: You want the coordinates sorted into a ring. WebMonster provided a link to a couple of Contour Tracing algorithms - one of those will work well.